# Prevent the users from adding columns in the SP list

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hope you're doing well!

I would like prevent the users from adding columns in the SP list knowing that they have an edit role so they can upload a file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default permissions for members is "edit", which allows users to create, modify, and delete lists There is another permission level called "contribute" which only allows users to create, modify, and delete documents, but not lists. Unfortunately, it can be a little tricky to make this change, depending on if you're in sharepoint online in a modern, group connected site vs on-prem or a classic site. [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253255/assigning-contribute-permission-instead-of-edit-to-the-sharepoint-modern-tea) is another question that addresses this for modern sites.

For classic sites it's easier, just get to the advanced permissions page and modify the permissions to change the members group from edit to contribute.

Comment: Hey @Mike2500 , thank you for your solution, everything worked fine and sorry for the late reply but it's been a very busy 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion, you could refer to this article for more information about permission levels in SharePoint:

[User permissions and permission levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)

Comment: Thank you @Elsie Lu_MSFT for the additional info and sorry for the late reply, I really appreciate it.